# How to force package to be recompiled on Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

TL;DR: Is there a way to force to recompile a package every time an image is generated?

I have a bbappend with a `do_deploy_append` appending to a file and if I modify this step, the recipe will not be recompiled when generating an image using it. This can lead to errors pretty hard to ind. Bitbake assumes it has been unchanged. I have only 2 packages like this, very small.

Is there a parameter to force those package being cleaned and recompiled without manually do it?

I am using Yocto morty

Comment: How are you adding the file? Normally, bitbake should detect that the file has been modified and automatically rebuild the recipe. Which version of OE / Yocto are you running?

Comment: I have updated the description. It was not complete indeed

Comment: Could you add an example? I've got bbappends both replacing files and modifying files using eg `sed?  in a `do_install_append()`-step. They all works as intended. Besides, which version of OE / Yocto are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/agherzan/meta-raspberrypi/blob/master/recipes-bsp/bootfiles/rpi-config_git.bb

I have a bbappend extending this configuration.

Comment: Ah, that makes it more interesting... Unfortunately, all my recipes with bbappends do actually use a `do_install` task. As `${B}` is completely unused in `rpi-config_git.bb` I guess that you're modifying files in `${S}` (which also could be bad for rerunning the task). Would you mind to try and replace your `do_install_append` with a `do_deploy_append`?

Comment: Exactly, it seems that bitbake ignores the `${S}` directory, it would actually make sense but in this particular case, the deploy append doesn't make a difference. I think the recipe iteself needs a rewriting, because this looks like a kind of hack here

Comment: Yes, a rewrite to install stuff to B, then deploy from B to deploy_dir would normally be a good idea. Hm, a nice rewrite would likely be to install to B and make all modifications from `do_deploy` in B; then use the modified files from B to deploy them... I'm not using any RPi, though, so I won't be testing it. Though, I would have assumed that changes to `do_deploy` by an append would have been recognized by bitbake...

Comment: This is pretty uncommon, it should not happen in the deploy, I understand bitbake isn't aware them.
To answer the question, I would also take another case. If in a recipe, `SRCREV="${AUTOREV}"`, bitbake will not check if there's a new commit on this repo. Working on a project in development daily needs this variable set this way, but I find myself cleaning everytime.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you want a task to always be executed, you should use the `[nostamp]` varflag on this task, which should be set to `"1"`. For example, if you want the recipe to be recompiled every time, you should add the below line to the package's recipe:

```
do_compile[nostamp] = "1"
```

To always execute the `do_configure` task, you should add the following line:

```
do_configure[nostamp] = "1"
```

This applies for any task that you need to always be executed. Have a look here for more information on `nostamp` variable flag: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3.2/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!